# Why do we need an open interval to define local maxima?

Tags: calculus

We say that $f(x)$ has a local maximum at $\tilde{x}$ if  for every $x$ in some open interval $(\tilde{x}-\delta,\tilde{x}+\delta)$, $\delta>0$ we have $f(\tilde{x})>f(x)$.

Why do we need an open interval? Why can't a closed interval be good enough?

Comment: Obviously you can find a closed interval inside every open interval and vice-versa. If you mean that it should be like $[x^*,x^*+\delta]$, then look at $x^3$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We actually need a *neighbourhood* of $\tilde x$; i.e. a set that contains an open interval around $\tilde x$. This is just by definition of what "local" means.

E.g. to be a local maximum would be a pretty empty statement if we were allowed to use the closed interval $[\tilde x,\tilde x] = \{\tilde x\}$... We thus (intuitively) need to look at what other values $f$ attains "close to $\tilde x$", or, "in a neighbourhood of $\tilde x$"; there you go :).

Another example to show that a general closed interval will not suffice (it is obvious that $[x_0,x_1]$ must have $x_0 = \tilde x$ or $x_1 = \tilde x$ or $\tilde x$ would be in $(x_0,x_1)$ as well, i.e. $[x_0,x_1]$ would be a neighbourhood of $\tilde x$ after all). Namely, take $f(x) = x$ and the interval $[-1,0]$ about $0$; since $f(x)>0$ for all $x >0$ it is not natural to regard $0$ as a local maximum of $f$.

---

On the other hand, if $x_0 < \tilde x < x_1$, then $[x_0,x_1]$ contains the open interval $(x_0,x_1)$, hence is a neighbourhood. In this sense, closed intervals *where $\tilde x$ is not the endpoint* are fine. Moreover, if we have an open interval $(\tilde x-\delta, \tilde x+\delta)$, then we have the inclusions:

$$\left(\tilde x - \frac\delta2, \tilde x+\frac \delta2\right) \subset \left[\tilde x - \frac\delta2, \tilde x+ \frac\delta2\right] \subset (\tilde x -\delta, \tilde x +\delta)$$

showing that "closed intervals where $\tilde x$ is not the endpoint" provide an equally valid notion local maximum as "open intervals" (but of course the latter is shorter). Thus taking closed intervals in your definition is *equivalent* to taking open intervals.

The reason for preferring open intervals is that in the more general field of *topology*, they generalise to so-called *open sets*, while closed intervals generalise to *closed sets*. But in general, not every neighbourhood (with *open sets* rather than intervals now) will contain a closed subset that is still a neighbourhood (however, as we have seen, this *is* true in $\Bbb R$). So, as there is only one of the two definitions that generalises in a natural way to general *topological spaces*, your book/professor has decided to give that definition, avoiding unnecessary confusion later on.

---

Lastly, let me elaborate on why this notion of *neighbourhood* is "natural". For suppose that there were no (set containing an) open interval $(x_0, x_1)$ about $\tilde x$ satisfying the given condition. Then for this to be possible, we need that:

$$\forall \delta > 0: \exists x: |\tilde x - x| < \delta, f(x) \ge f(\tilde x)$$

This means: "however close you look at $\tilde x$, there is always a point $x$ in your scope where $f(x) \ge f(\tilde x)$." Now hopefully you agree that such $\tilde x$ should *not* be called a local maximum.

Comment: From your explanation my next question would why do we need an open interval for neighbourhood? The example you gave has $\delta = 0$ so that example is automatically ruled out. Can you give me some other example that clarifies the reason for an open interval?

Answer (score 2):

For $\,(x_0,f(x_0)) \,$ to be a local maximum we need that here

$$\exists\,\epsilon>0\;\;s.t.\;\;f(x_0)\ge f(x)\;\;\forall\,x\in(x_0-\epsilon\,,\,x_0+\epsilon)$$

It's a matter of definition. Funny enough, whenever a function's definition domain has end points its values of the end points *automatically* (i.e. by definition) are local extrema...

Comment: I see what you mean now - apologies. Probably I am too tied up in general topology to assess these matters properly. The proper definition of course needs the open sets to be those of the subspace topology on the domain. In that sense, there is no problem with endpoints (at present stage it probably would be better to assume that $\tilde x$ is an interior point of the domain to avoid these pathologies).

Answer (score 0):

If we use closed interval instead of open then for any function $f:A\to \mathbb R$, any point $x_0\in A$ where $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$,  will be a local minimum or maximum:

If $f'(x_0)>0$ then using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of the limit it is not hard to show that there exist a $\delta>0$ s.t. $f(x)>f(x_0)$ for all $x\in(x_0,x_0+\delta)$...